# Shape of a floating candle floating in an infinitely large cylindrical tub of water that maintains its height

Tags: fluid-statics, buoyancy

I was asked by a friend to determine the shape of an axially symmetric candle floating in water in a tub in such a manner that the wick maintains its height with respect to the ground. The fall in height due to depletion of wax is exactly offset by the gain in height due to buoyancy. What relationship between density of water, density of wax and radius and height of candle above water guarantees this? The second harder part of the problem is when we consider the size of the cylindrical tub finite( area A ) instead of having an infinite extent.

I tried to write the differential equation by equating the thin slice that burns in time dt with the thin slice that rises above surface in the same infinitely small time interval but I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you have work you've tried it's best you include it otherwise we have no idea where you're having trouble. One should also take care to more clearly and mathematically define the problem of one wants to solve it mathematically.

Comment: A "flower vase" shaped  candle is floating in water burning . Part of it submerged and  height h above. For h to be constant what should be the equation of the transverse section of the candle. I suspect exponential curve but can't prove it quite exactly.

Comment: You don't need to put it in the comments, you can directly edit your question to include the relevant information, but you also should include any work you've attempted.